# insert format number in database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

I'm developing a `Shopping Cart` in `PHP`; after I have all my products, I have a `$total`.

If I have `$ 14589.579` then I use `number_format($total,2);` to see `$14,589.58`.

But when I try to insert it into my database, I only see `14`. The field on my database is type `double`.

This is my query:

```
"INSERT INTO cotizacion (
    idcotiza, idcli, idusuario, fechacotiza, pais, proyecto, notas, formapago, 
    tiempoentrega, flete, instalacion, venta, subtotal, descuento, total, 
    totalpesosmex, status, fecha2
) VALUES (
    NULL, '".$_SESSION['idcliente']."','".$_SESSION['idusuario']."', '".$fechatoday."',
   '".$pais."', '".$proyecto."', '".$notas."', '".$formapago."', '".$fechaentrega."',
   '".$flete."', '".$instalacion."', '".$venta."', NULL, NULL, '".$total."',
   '".$totalpesosmex."', 'Abierto', NULL
);"
```

Any idea about what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `DECIMAL` to store money values.

Second, use `REPLACE` to remove the characters you dont want in a MySQL level.

Comment: It's the only way??... Or... Ammmmm... Is there a way to rollback the format?